# How can I prevent insertion into a table through trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I've to prevent the insertion into table when the number of rows having colour as Red exceeds 100. Here's the code that i've written, just dont know what to write in the blank.

```
CREATE TRIGGER onRegisterInsert BEFORE INSERT ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
    IF New.Colour='Red' THEN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM table_name WHERE Colour='Red';
        if n > 100 THEN
          ---
        END IF
    END IF
END
```

I thought of writing `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'` to prevent insertion but i dont want to throw an error, because i'm inserting a list of data and if i throw an error the insertion of data after this will also be stopped.

I also thought of writing an after insert trigger instead of before.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER onRegisterInsert After INSERT ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF New.Colour='Red' THEN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @count FROM table_name WHERE Colour='Red';
        IF (@count >= 100) THEN
        delete from table_name new;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END //
```

but this code too gives an error.

Comment: I don't think MySQL offers an "instead of" trigger.

Comment: Maybe, in your `after insert` you can use `delete from table_name where id = new.id` (where you replace `id` with the actual pk of the table)

Comment: No way to prevent the insertion of one record from the whole data array only. Either insert all or eject the whole insertion.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is use `INSERT IGNORE` in the calling app instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: Yes, this may solve... and additionally the BEFORE INSERT trigger must alter PK (or any unique column/expression) value of wrong record to the value of any existing record. But this must be tested...

Comment: Method is correct! [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73NAjrXRL2oYQutcTmVxbd/0) with trace info.